# Make label float right and sit vertically centred

Tags: html, css

I have created a `nav` bar and its working fine except when the screen is 768px or less the 'menu toggle' button does not sit on the right of the screen. Instead it appears right after the image (see my example for the issue).

**How can I make the `<label class="menu-icon">` sit on the right of the page (float right) on screens smaller than 768px?** I've tried float right (that messes up the vertical alignment - it needs to sit in the middle vertically).

The following doesn't work:

```
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

or

```
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
    float: right;
}
```

```css
.nav-widget {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.nav-widget .header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-widget .header .left-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav-widget .header .right-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

/* How can I align this on the right? */
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: none;
  right: 0px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .right-nav {
  max-height: 240px !important;
  display: block;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .right-nav > .widget {
  display: block;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-widget .header .left-nav {
    display: inline-block; /*table-cell;*/
  }
  .nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
    display: inline-block; /*table-cell;*/
  }
  .nav-widget .header .right-nav {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0 !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav-widget .header .right-nav a {
   display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-widget">
 <nav class="header">  

  <div class="left-nav">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
  </div>

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />  
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label> 

  <div class="right-nav">
   <a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a>
   <a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>

<p>The menu toggle button should sit on the right of the page not right next to the image.</p>
```

Comment: why use floats and not something like Flex?

Comment: well either way, seems the issue is that your `.left-nav` class at that resolutiion has a display property of `inline-block`, so does the `menu-icon` class. You can technically change both of them to `display: table-cell` for view that sort of works. But honestly I'd use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to .nav-widget .header class.

```
  .nav-widget .header{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
 }
@media (max-width: 768px)
.nav-widget .header .right-nav {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0 !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: block;
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I hope this what u r expecting

Demo:

```css
.nav-widget {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.nav-widget .header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-widget .header .left-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav-widget .header .right-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

/* How can I align this on the right? */
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: none;
  right: 0px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .right-nav {
  max-height: 240px !important;
  display: block;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .right-nav > .widget {
  display: block;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-widget .header .left-nav {
    display: inline-block; /*table-cell;*/
  }
  .nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
    display: inline-block; /*table-cell;*/
  }
.nav-widget .header .right-nav {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0 !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: block;
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

  

  .nav-widget .header .right-nav a {
   display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-widget">
 <nav class="header">  

  <div class="left-nav">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
  </div>

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />  
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label> 

  <div class="right-nav">
   <a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a>
   <a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>

<p>The menu toggle button should sit on the right of the page not right next to the image.</p>
```

Comment: if you now click the menu icon, the dropdown menu sits on the right not below.

Comment: @sazr check my answer now

Comment: whether u got the expected answer? @sazr

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple `position: absolute` on your `.menu-icon` do the trick:

```css
.nav-widget {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.nav-widget .header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-widget .header .left-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav-widget .header .right-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: none;
  right: 0px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .right-nav {
  max-height: 240px !important;
  display: block;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .right-nav > .widget {
  display: block;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.nav-widget .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-widget .header .left-nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav-widget .header .menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; /* Add this position absolute */
    
    /* Add extra 'margin' */
    top: 50%;
    right: 1em;
  }
  .nav-widget .header .right-nav {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0 !important;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav-widget">
 <nav class="header">  

  <div class="left-nav">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
  </div>

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />  
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label> 

  <div class="right-nav">
   <a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a>
   <a href="#"><span>Press Me</span></a>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>

<p>The menu toggle button should sit on the right of the page not right next to the image.</p>
```

Comment: thanks, how can I keep it vertically aligned middle though?

Comment: @sazr Just set the `top` of your `.menu-icon` to `50%` like this `top: 50%;`. I updated the code in the snippet ;)

Comment: yes thats what I tried but if you open the menu the button jumps down because the height has increased and  '50% of the new height' pulls it down

Comment: @sazr Yes, I noticed it too. this problem should not be solved in css but rather on the side of the structure of your html. I think it would be wise to put the elements `.left-nav`, `.menu-btn` and `.menu-icon` in a same container and let `.right-nav` alone maybe like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vaqg1s7n/1/). However, you will have to use javascript to animate your dropdown because you won't be able to use the `~` operator anymore.

Comment: @sazr Can you please `upvote` and `validate` an answer ? ;)